# Jenkins svn branches

Tags: maven, svn, jenkins

I recently created an automated process to run multi-step Maven builds for my organization. But i am having difficulty committing the version changes on svn

I want to update this file contents and compile my code and then commit this file back to svn. So that SVN has latest build version number.

How do I commit this changed file to SVN.

Ty very much.

Comment: What difficulties do you have?

Comment: i don't know how to make a new version of my project with jenkins and upload on the svn

Comment: In short words i want to modify my workspace path or copy the project from jenkins workspace to svn repo...

Answer (score 0):

I invoke top-level Maven targets to release in svn:
my goals is: release:perform  -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:http://XXX

This is my maven error in jenkins:

```
[maven] $ cmd.exe /C "D:\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\mvn.cmd release:perform -DconnectionUrl=scm:svn:http://10.10.20.151/svn/repos/aubay/test/jenkins/branches && exit %%ERRORLEVEL%%"
channel stopped
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building jenkins 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:perform (default-cli) @ jenkins ---
[ERROR] Cannot perform release - the preparation step was stopped mid-way. Please re-run release:prepare to continue, or perform the release from an SCM tag.
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.199 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-24T15:48:29+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/150M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2:perform (default-cli) on project jenkins: Cannot perform release - the preparation step was stopped mid-way. Please re-run release:prepare to continue, or perform the release from an SCM tag. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```